# How to sort foursquare venues by name (i.e. sorting

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, foursquare

I'm using the foursquare venues API to populate a select menu and list in my web app.  I'd like to sort the venues alphabetically by name.

Here is a JSON response from the foursquare API, which has some venues:

```
[ { "reasons": { "count": 1, "items": [ { "summary": "This spot is popular on foursquare", "type": "general", "reasonName": "globalInteractionReason" } ] }, "venue": { "id": "4c6ee03fb5a5236a74744b52", "name": "Peninsular Paper Dam", "contact": {}, "location": { "address": "1265 Leforge Rd", "crossStreet": "at Huron River Rd", "lat": 42.256628, "lng": -83.623933, "distance": 892, "postalCode": "48198", "city": "Ypsilanti", "state": "MI", "country": "United States", "cc": "US" }, "categories": [ { "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d165941735", "name": "Scenic Lookout", "pluralName": "Scenic Lookouts", "shortName": "Scenic Lookout", "icon": { "prefix": "https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/parks_outdoors/sceniclookout_", "suffix": ".png" }, "primary": true } ], "verified": false, "stats": { "checkinsCount": 31, "usersCount": 12, "tipCount": 0 }, "likes": { "count": 0, "groups": [] }, "specials": { "count": 0, "items": [] }, "photos": { "count": 2, "groups": [] } } }, { "reasons": { "count": 1, "items": [ { "summary": "This spot is popular on foursquare", "type": "general", "reasonName": "globalInteractionReason" } ] }, "venue": { "id": "4ba58202f964a520cb0d39e3", "name": "Benito's Pizza", "contact": { "phone": "7349610707", "formattedPhone": "(734) 961-0707" }, "location": { "address": "1088 N Huron River Dr", "lat": 42.256532, "lng": -83.629082, "distance": 1035, "postalCode": "48197", "city": "Ypsilanti", "state": "MI", "country": "United States", "cc": "US" }, "categories": [ { "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1ca941735", "name": "Pizza Place", "pluralName": "Pizza Places", "shortName": "Pizza", "icon": { "prefix": "https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/food/pizza_", "suffix": ".png" }, "primary": true } ], "verified": false, "stats": { "checkinsCount": 50, "usersCount": 34, "tipCount": 0 }, "url": "http://www.benitospizza.com/", "likes": { "count": 0, "groups": [] }, "menu": { "type": "foodAndBeverage", "url": "https://foursquare.com/v/benitos-pizza/4ba58202f964a520cb0d39e3/menu", "mobileUrl": "https://foursquare.com/v/4ba58202f964a520cb0d39e3/device_menu" }, "specials": { "count": 0, "items": [] }, "photos": { "count": 0, "groups": [] } } } ]
```

I'm able to parse this response with this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < venues.length; i++) {
   name = venues[i]['venue']['name'];
   category = venues[i]['venue']['categories'][0]['name'];
   icon = venues[i]['venue']['categories'][0]['icon']['prefix'];
   icon = icon.slice(0, -1); // remove trailing "_" character
   icon = icon + venues[i]['venue']['categories'][0]['icon']['suffix'];
   address = venues[i]['venue']['location']['address'];
   city = venues[i]['venue']['location']['city'];
   state = venues[i]['venue']['location']['state'];
   distance_meters = venues[i]['venue']['location']['distance'];
   distance_miles = distance_meters / 1609.34;
   distance_miles = Math.round(distance_miles*100)/100;
   x = 1; // in the product use i for index below
   HTMLmarkupList += "<li><a href=\"#lister_" + x + "\"><img src=\"" + icon + "\" class=\"ui-li-thumb\" style=\"margin: 23px 10px\" onerror=\"ImgError(this);\">" + "<h3 style=\"margin-left: -40px\">" + name + "</h3><p style=\"margin-left: -40px\">" + category + "</p><p style=\"margin-left: -40px\">" + address + ", " + city + ", " + state + "</p><p style=\"margin-left: -40px\">" + distance_miles + " miles from you.</p></a></li>";

   HTMLmarkupSelect += "<option value\"" + i + "\">" + name + "</option>";
}
```

Right now, the value of the select is just i, but as I'll be needing to store other variables along with the name in my database I may update the value in each select option to include things like the address, city, state, etc....  I mention this because if I was only using the name in the select, I could just build an array of names and use the javascript sort method.

Can anyone help with how to sort the venues alphabetically by name?  Thanks.

Comment: The Array `.sort()` function can be passed a comparator function. That function is passed two array elements to compare, and should return a number that's negative, zero, or positive, according to the proper ordering of the two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information:

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Example:

```
venues.sort(function(a,b){
  if(a.venue.name == b.venue.name) return 0;
  return (a.venue.name < b.venue.name) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: @Pointy thx for that. although that page contains proper information. Fixed my function.